# Swapping columns of the Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, swap

I made this code in order to swap places with the first column and the last column in a `3x3` Matrix. I would need to use 2 different methods, one to print the original matrix and one to print the modified matrix.

I was able to do the first one, but I have problems with the second.

```
public class SwapMatrix {    
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int matrix [][] = 
            {{3, 4, 5}, 
            {7, 8, 9}, 
            {1, 2, 3}};
        System.out.println("\n Normal Matrix:");
        print(matrix);
        
        
        //int matrixModified [][] = swap(matrix);
        //System.out.println("\n New Matrix:");
        //print(matrixModified);
    }
    
    public static void print (int matrix[][]){
        for (int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++){
           for (int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){
               System.out.print(matriz [i][j]+ "\t");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the matrix backwards, all you have to do is to count reverse in your loop.

```
public static void printReverse (int matrix[][]){
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){             // lines
       for (int j=matrix[0].length-1; j>=0; j--){    // columns backwards
           System.out.print(matrix [i][j]+ "\t");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `swap()` method in two ways: either by *creating a new matrix* or by swapping the columns of the given matrix *in place*.

**1.** Firstly, you need to create a *new matrix*.

And then iterate over it with a nested `for` loop assigning the elements of each *row* in the new matrix in reversed order. I.e. the value of the first element of the *row* at position `0` would be assigned to the element at position `matrix[0].length - 1` and vice versa (*the same hold true for all other elements*).

```
public static int[][] swap(int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            result[row][(matrix[0].length - 1) - col] = matrix[row][col];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**2.** To swap the given matrix in place, you need to create a nested `for` loop. Iteration in the inner loop should happen only until the middle of the array representing each row (*that's important, if'll iterate over the full length of a row elements will get swapped twice and the matrix will remain the same*).

```
public static int[][] swapInPlace(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length / 2; col++) {
            int temp = matrix[row][(matrix[0].length - 1) - col];
            matrix[row][(matrix[0].length - 1) - col] = matrix[row][col];
            matrix[row][col] = temp;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

***Sidenote:*** although `int matrix[][]` is a valid syntax inherited from the **C** language, it's not a good practice to use it because this notation mixes two completely different notions: a *variable name* and a *type*. The preferred way to define an array `int[][] matrix`.